# Why is this correlated subquery faster than a window function?

Tags: oracle12c, sql-execution-plan

Two queries:

```sql
select tbraccd_pidm, 
       max(tbraccd_balance) 
       keep (dense_rank first order by tbraccd_tran_number) 
       over (partition by tbraccd_pidm)
from tbraccd;
```

```sql
select tbraccd_pidm, tbraccd_balance
from tbraccd a
where tbraccd_tran_number = (select max(tbraccd_tran_number)
                             from tbraccd b 
                             where b.tbraccd_pidm = a.tbraccd_pidm);
```

And their autotraces:

[image]

[image]

`PK_TBRACCD` is indexed off of `TBRACCD_PIDM` and `TBRACCD_TRAN_NUMBER`.

According to the V$Stats, the first query uses 2.43x CPU to complete the first call over the second call, and approximately the same difference in DB time.

They're using the same index, and they're each performing a FULL SCAN. How come the second function performs so much better?

Answer (score 0):

The first query:

```sql
select tbraccd_pidm, 
       max(tbraccd_balance) 
       keep (dense_rank first order by tbraccd_tran_number) 
       over (partition by tbraccd_pidm)
from tbraccd;
```

Will return all the rows from the table; you find the maximum in the `SELECT` clause but it is not used in a `WHERE` clause to filter the result set so you are returning every row.

It is also different as you are using `DENSE_RANK FIRST`, which finds the minimum, and not `DENSE_RANK LAST` (or `DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY ... DESC`) to find the maximum.

In comparison:

```sql
select tbraccd_pidm, tbraccd_balance
from tbraccd a
where tbraccd_tran_number = (select max(tbraccd_tran_number)
                             from tbraccd b 
                             where b.tbraccd_pidm = a.tbraccd_pidm);
```

There is a `WHERE` clause and the query only needs to return a sub-set of the results.

---

If you want the queries to be equivalent then the first query should be:

```sql
SELECT tbraccd_pidm, 
       tbraccd_balance
FROM   (
  SELECT tbraccd_pidm, 
         tbraccd_balance,
         RANK() OVER (
           partition by tbraccd_pidm ORDER BY tbraccd_tran_number DESC
         ) AS rnk
  FROM   tbraccd
)
WHERE  rnk = 1;
```

or

```sql
SELECT tbraccd_pidm,
       tbraccd_balance
FROM   (
  select tbraccd_pidm,
         tbraccd_balance,
         tbraccd_tran_number,
         MAX(tbraccd_tran_number) OVER (partition by tbraccd_pidm) AS max_number
  from tbraccd
)
WHERE  tbraccd_tran_number = max_number;
```

---

If you expect the queries to only return a single row for each `tbaccd_pidm` then another option is to could change from using an analytic function in the first query to an aggregation function:

```sql
select tbraccd_pidm, 
       max(tbraccd_balance) 
         keep (dense_rank LAST order by tbraccd_tran_number) 
from   tbraccd
GROUP BY tbraccd_pidm;
```